# Vue '#' to '?#' in before the route. What does it mean?

Tags: vue.js, routes

When I host my vue application it hosts on `localhost:8080/#/` which is correct and then I navigate to the login page and I try to login, and it accepts my correct login credentials, there are no errors, but it remains on the login page and changes the route to `localhost:8080/?#/login` and if I then login from there, it works as it should and logs you in and redirects you to your home page etc.

Why is this caused and can I change it?

Comment: You should probably start here: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#html5-history-mode)

> The default mode for vue-router is hash mode - it uses the URL hash to simulate a full URL so that the page won't be reloaded when the URL changes.

> To get rid of the hash, we can use the router's history mode, which leverages the history.pushState API to achieve URL navigation without a page reload:

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [...]
})
```

You might also need to [configure](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations) ur webserver to redirect the request to ur index file and ignore the default behavior and search for directories as there are slashes in the url